Meta-feature analysis: split data for computation on available memory
I am working with the meta-feature extractor package: pymfe for complexity analysis.
On a small dataset, this is not a problem, for example.
pip install -U pymfe

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from pymfe.mfe import MFE

data = load_iris()
X= data.data
y = data.target

extractor = MFE(features=[ "t1"], groups=["complexity"],
                  summary=["min", "max", "mean", "sd"])
extractor.fit(X,y)
extractor.extract()
(['t1'], [0.12])

My dataset is large (32690, 80) and this computation gets killed for exessive memory usage. I work on Ubuntu 24.04 having 32GB RAM.
To reproduce scenario:
# Generate the dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=20_000,n_features=80,
    n_informative=60, n_classes=5, random_state=42)

extractor = MFE(features=[ "t1"], groups=["complexity"],
                  summary=["min", "max", "mean", "sd"])
extractor.fit(X,y)
extractor.extract()
Killed

Question:
How do I split this task to compute on small partitions of the dataset, and combine final results (averaging)?

Managed to find a workaround.
# helper functions
def split_dataset(X, y, n_splits):
    # data splits
    split_X = np.array_split(X, n_splits)
    split_y = np.array_split(y, n_splits)
    return split_X, split_y

def compute_meta_features(X, y):
    # meta-features for a partition
    extractor = MFE(features=["t1"], groups=["complexity"], 
        summary=["min", "max", "mean", "sd"])
    extractor.fit(X, y)
    return extractor.extract()

def average_results(results):
    # summary of results
    features = results[0][0]
    summary_values = np.mean([result[1] for result in results], axis=0)
    return features, summary_values

# Split dataset
n_splits = 10  # ten splits
split_X, split_y = split_dataset(X, y, n_splits)

#  meta-features 
results = [compute_meta_features(X_part, y_part) for X_part, y_part in zip(split_X, split_y)]

# Combined results
final_features, final_summary = average_results(results)



StratifiedKFold in the sklearn.model_selection is ideal for your case to create multiple balanced partitions while preserving the class distribution in each split.
Here is the code
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from pymfe.mfe import MFE

# Generate the large dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=20000, n_features=80, n_informative=60, n_classes=5, random_state=42)

# Function to process each partition and extract features
def process_partition(X, y):
    extractor = MFE(features=["t1"], groups=["complexity"], summary=["min", "max", "mean", "sd"])
    extractor.fit(X, y)
    return extractor.extract()

# Function to combine results from all partitions
def combine_results(partition_results):
    combined = {}
    for features, values in partition_results:
        for feature, value in zip(features, values):
            combined.setdefault(feature, []).append(value)
    return {feature: np.mean(values) for feature, values in combined.items()}

# Create stratified partitions using StratifiedKFold
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
partition_results = [process_partition(X[train_idx], y[train_idx]) for train_idx, _ in skf.split(X, y)]

# Combine the results from all partitions
final_result = combine_results(partition_results)
print(final_result)


Uhm, this sounds interesting...

thank you for this answer. This is done at the expense of compute time. On n_samples=1_000 it's about 10x slower than my answer (8.381s against 1.267s)
